# How to update a field in a nested JSON document in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

How to update a field in a nested JSON document in Mongo?

```
{
  _id : '123'
    friends: [
      {name: 'allen', emails: [
        {
          video: {
          name:'abc',
          subType:'video',
          status:'active'
              }
        }, 
        {
          video: {
          name:'abc',
          subType:'video',
          status:'active'
              }  
        }
        ]}
    ]
 }
```

I have tried the following query but I am not able to update the document.

```
db.users.update ({_id: '123'}, {$set: {"friends.0.emails.0.video.status" : 'Inactive'} })
```

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1):

As per MongoDB documentaion [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) The update method can modify specific fields of an existing document or documents or replace an existing document entirely, depending on the [update parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter).

By default, the [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) method updates a single document. Set the [Multi Parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) to update all documents that match the query criteria.

The **`update()`** method has the following form:

**`Changed in version 3.6.`**

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

For example to update the JSON documents through update command in mongo shell, which you have been mention.

Here I have created the test database & also users collection based on your mention documents.

```
> use test
switched to db test
>db.createCollection("users");
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.users.insert({
...   "_id" : '123',
...     "friends": [
...       {name: 'allen', emails: [
...         {
...           video: {
...           name:'abc',
...           subType:'video',
...           status:'active'
...               }
...         },
...         {
...           "video": {
...           "name":'abc',
...           "subType":'video',
...           "status":'active'
...               }
...         }
...         ]}
...     ]
...  })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Now I want to see the inserted documents in users collections in mongo shell through the command such as

```
> db.users.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : "123",
        "friends" : [
                {
                        "name" : "allen",
                        "emails" : [
                                {
                                        "video" : {
                                                "name" : "abc",
                                                "subType" : "video",
                                                "status" : "active"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "video" : {
                                                "name" : "abc",
                                                "subType" : "video",
                                                "status" : "active"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

As you want to update the status : Inactive , which comes under the metadata of video.
The update statement command will be as follows

```
> db.users.update ({"_id": '123'}, {$set: {"friends.0.emails.0.video.status" : 'Inactive'} });
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Again I will check through the find method , it has been modified or not.

```
> db.users.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : "123",
        "friends" : [
                {
                        "name" : "allen",
                        "emails" : [
                                {
                                        "video" : {
                                                "name" : "abc",
                                                "subType" : "video",
                                                "status" : "Inactive"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "video" : {
                                                "name" : "abc",
                                                "subType" : "video",
                                                "status" : "active"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```